# manipulating equivalence relation on permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, equivalence-relations, symmetric-groups

im trying to prove the following On the set $S_n$ of permutations define $σ_1 \sim σ_2$ if there exists a permutation τ such that
$σ_1 = τσ_2τ^{-1}$

Show that $\sim$ defines an equivalence relation on the set $S_n$of permutations.

so this might be a dumb question but im confused if i can left/right multiply like i would with matrices for example can do the following:

$σ_1 \sim σ_2$ implies $σ_1 = τσ_2τ^{-1} \implies$ $τ^{-1}σ_1 = τ^{-1}τσ_2τ^{-1} \implies τ^{-1}σ_1 = idσ_2τ^{-1}$

this is the step where i am not sure if i can do the following

$τ^{-1}σ_1τ = σ_2τ^{-1}τ \implies  τ^{-1}σ_1τ = σ_2 id $

and this shows that

$σ_2 \sim σ_1$

am i allowed to do this in order to show the relation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can multiply an equation either from right or from left with the same element, and you'll still get an equation.

$$\sigma_1=\tau\sigma_2\tau^{-1}\ \iff\ \tau^{-1}\sigma_1\tau=\sigma_2$$

So, $\tau^{-1}$ will confirm $\sigma_2\sim\sigma_1$.